# Does BLE Data Transfer require pairing (pairless bt data transfer)

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

For a project of mine I need a pairless bluetooth data transfer. I have first thought about doing it with BLE IBeacons but they can only advertise a very limited amount of data. I looked further through the Apple documentation and found [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/transferring_data_between_bluetooth_low_energy_devices) tutorial about Central/ Peripheral 
 BLE data transfer. I've implemented the code in my project but even though the devices were very close together they could not "see" each other. I have since looked up on the Internet and could not find a hint about whether the devices need pairing or not and what the problem of mine could be(the code is not throwing any errors nor warnings).
If it does require pairing, is there some way to do that in the background without requiring the user to perform an action, so that I could theoretically advertise some kind of pair request via. IBeacons to then transfer the data? If that's not the case, is there even a way to transfer data (mono directional, round about 512 bytes) between nearby bluetooth devices without user actions?

greets from germany!

Comment: BLE does not require pairing. For the devices shall be able to connect to each other, one device must be discoverable (or must advertise), and the other device must scan. I think you should read some BLE introduction before going straight into a project.

Answer (score 1):

To get started with Bluetooth Low Energy or any other protocol, it's best to learn how it works. At least basics.

Simplifying. BLE allows you to send data:

- "Passive" (without conncetion) - over Advertisement Data. The size of the packages depends on the BLE version.
- "Active" (requires connection with the device) - bidrirectional comunication. In this case size of the data package also depends on the BLE version.
  Bonding and pairing is a separate issues.

I suggested you look at the following book:

https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/getting-started-with/9781491900550/

The websites of BLE module manufacturers also offer a lot of information about this technology. For example Nordic or TI. Very often with sample programs for various platforms.

For iOS:

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/712/

https://developer.apple.com/bluetooth/

You may also be interested in sending more data without connection using version BLE 5.0

https://www.bluetooth.com/blog/exploring-bluetooth5-whats-new-in-advertising/